# WPF Use DataGrid With DataGridTemplateColumn thas has a ComboBox with Datagrid inside

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I have a situation where i have a List of T bound to a datagrid. In the collection there is a property that is also a collection. This is very common. However in this case i want to use a datagrid UI object that i have styled and put it in a ComboBox because i find it very nice to have a dropdownitem in a datagridcolumn. Hopefully this makes sense, to demonstrate my story with code:

```
<DataGrid
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
    ColumnWidth="*"
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="Property1" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="Property2" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="Property3" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox>
                        <DataGrid
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            CanUserAddRows="False"
                            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                            ColumnWidth="*"
                            HeadersVisibility="Column"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjectPropertyCollection}">

                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="SubProperty1" />
                                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="SubProperty2" />
                                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="SubProperty3" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The code above is a stripped down version of the exact experience i want. As you can see i added the DataGrid for the PropertyCollection inside a DataGridTemplateColumn. In which a ComboBox is placed with in it one ListBoxItem that is the DataGrid.

The only thing what's is a unwanted behaviour in this setup is that the DataGrid is a ComboBoxItem, meaning when you open the ComboBox and click on the item the entire DataGrid will expand and all style etc.. don't work anymore in the way i want.

So can i either disable the behaviour of the ComboBoxItem OR inherit somekind of style to let the Second Datagrid be displayed as a ComboBox which expand when you click it open?

Answer (score 0):

Following link might help, it will redirect to microsoft official page

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn?view=net-5.0**

Comment: Thanks for the help! However this isn't what i'm looking for. In simple terms i want the behaviour from the combobox DropDown style but then host only one thing. So strip the whole ItemSource stuff from a ComboBox and only use the Style of the ComboBox

Comment: Or looked at the other way arround, can i style a ComboBox to list it's items exactly how a datagrid does including headers? Like inheriting the Datagrid style?